# Property 'Child' does not support values of type 'xyz'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, user-controls

I try to implement a UserControl from my windows-form application into a WPF application. The UserControl is generated and works so far.

When I compile the WPF-application I do not get any error but the Design can NOT be loaded due to the error message: Property '**Child' does not support values of type 'UserControl1**'

I use following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1LL_Neu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:LowLightGrab="clr-namespace:LowLightGrab;assembly=LowLightGrab"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="205" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,56,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" >
        <LowLightGrab:UserControl1 />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

When I run the application anyway the detailed error messages is as follows: ***Unable to load DLL 'VCECLB.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)***

For this reason I manually add the VCECLB.dll to my references.
[image]

Do I need to make another reference in my XAML code or...?

---

### UPDATE:

The UserControl solution consists of 2 projects while the VCECLB.dll is in the first one as it can see here:
[image]

Is this the reason for my error message because the UserControl of the namespace "**LowLightGrab**" can not access (find) the **VCECLB.dll** because it is in the other project?

Thanks!

Comment: As per screenshot VCECLB.dll still not under references!

Comment: `VCECLB.dll ` is not in your references. do you copy the dll in to output directory?

Comment: When I try to add reference directly to the folder "References" I get the error message **"A reference to \..\VCECLB.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"**. 
Therefore I drag the dll directly to the references and it went automatically to the place as shown.

Comment: @dotctor I also copied the **VCECLB.dll** to the output directory

Comment: I made an update (see question above)!

Comment: The problem is that my UserControl uses the VCECLB.dll from the project **FLExGrabber**. This **VCECLB.dll** is now not accessible from the new WPF-project. Why?

Comment: @Amit After re-compiling all projects again I am able to start the WPF-application with the limitation that I do NOT see the Designer! The error message is: **Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'LowLightGrab'. ...** This file is not downloaded from the web and in a local folder. How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: Right-click the LowLightGrab DLL and select properties.  Near the bottom of the properties dialog there should be a button that says "Unblock".  Click that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Amit I checked that allready but there is no button that says "Unblock". Both projects are on the local drive.

Comment: @dotctor Could you tell me where (folder) the VCECLB.dll needs to be copied?

Comment: @dotctor I don't know if it matters but the VCECLB.dll is a C++ dll. Question: Do I need to have this dll in the references folder or not?